# How to solve $\sin^{-1}(\sin16)$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

On solving this $\sin^{-1}[\sin(16)]$ .
I am finding both $(5π-16)$ and $(16-5π)$ to lie in the range of $[-π/2 , π/2]$ .

But my text book only mentions $(5π-16)$ as an answer.

So my question is, Is there any criteria or rule for getting the answer.

Please check me where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: Your question seems to be solely based on getting the answer, not on the concept behind it. Also you have not shown your work.

Comment: How did you find your 2 answers?

Comment: Please, while waiting for an answer, at least upvote  answers to questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4110765) you have asked a month ago, with a **perfect answer**

Comment: @Joe Yes I should have said "accept".

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4146787/21813) from 20 hours ago essentially answers your current question: just change $x$ from $10$ to $16$, and you will get $k$ equals $5$ instead of $3.$   And note that $\sin(16-5\pi)\neq \sin(5\pi-16).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

- $\sin(x)=-\sin(-x)$
- $\sin^{-1}(y) = -\sin^{-1}(-y)$ when $y \in [-1,1]$
- $\sin(x)=-\sin(x-\pi)=\sin(x-2\pi)=-\sin(x-3\pi)=\sin(x-4\pi)=-\sin(x-5\pi)$
- $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=x$ when $x \in [-\frac \pi2,\frac\pi2]$
- $16-5\pi\in [-\frac \pi2,\frac\pi2]$

Thus

- $\sin^{-1}(\sin(16))= -\sin^{-1}(\sin(16-5\pi)) = -(16-5\pi) = 5\pi-16$

The point to remember is that the sine function has period $2 \pi$, so something slightly more complicated happens if you only subtract an odd multiple of $\pi$.

Try to use a similar approach to $\cos^{-1}(\cos(16))$.  You might get something like  $\cos^{-1}(\cos(16))=\pi-\cos^{-1}(\cos(16-5\pi)) = \pi-(16-5\pi)= 6\pi-16$

Comment: Thanks a lot...